# How to disable Web cam microphone and use USB microphone as audio input

Tags: sound, alsa, webcam, microphone, mplayer

I have a webcam with builtin microphone, and I have a USB microphone.
I would like to record a video with webcam, but I want to record audio from USB mic, not from webcam mic.

When I use mplayer, I cannot record audio from USB mic from another tool (such as audacity, or simplescreenrecorder), because it seems webcam mic keeps input service (ALSA I guess) busy.

How can I solve this?

Comment: alsa is the driver, pulseaudio is the mixer. Try to customize your input source with `pavucontrol` (install it if needed)

Comment: using OBS Studio solved my problems